Parallel Lines arrow indicators not following line direction?
I'm trying to draw a parallelogram in tikz and show that it is made up of two sets of parallel lines. Here is a section of part of my code:
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (5,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (2,2.5);
        \coordinate (D) at (7,2.5);
        \draw (A)--(C)--(D) pic [draw=green, fill=green, fill opacity=0.5, angle radius=0.4cm] {angle=A--C--D};
        \draw (D)--(B)--(A) pic [draw=green, fill=green, fill opacity=0.5, angle radius=0.4cm] {angle=D--B--A};
        \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|,size=5pt](A,C B,D);
        \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||,size=5pt](A,B C,D);
        \draw[opacity=0] (A)--(B) node[opacity=1, currarrow,pos=0.75]{};
        \draw[opacity=0] (A)--(B) node[opacity=1, currarrow,pos=0.7]{};
        \draw[opacity=0] (C)--(D) node[opacity=1, currarrow,pos=0.75]{};
        \draw[opacity=0] (C)--(D) node[opacity=1, currarrow,pos=0.7]{};
        %arrows below point right instead of alone line to the end point
        \draw[opacity=0] (A)--(C) node[opacity=1, currarrow,pos=0.75]{};
        \draw[opacity=0] (B)--(D) node[opacity=1, currarrow,pos=0.7]{};
        %--
        \draw[opacity=0] (B)--(A)--(C) pic [draw=orange, fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5, angle radius=0.6cm] {angle=B--A--C};
        \draw[opacity=0] (C)--(D)--(B) pic [draw=orange, fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5, angle radius=0.6cm] {angle=C--D--B};
    \end{tikzpicture}

Which gives me the output shown in the picture below. The issue I have is that the arrows between points A--C and B--D are not following the line and are pointing right. Is there a way to make them follow the line AND be solid black arrows?


Note: I have all the correct packages for the above diagram, I'm just curious if there's a better way to maybe do the arrows on the left and right or maybe rotate them?

Please extend your code snipped to complete small document which we can test as it is. By this you will help us to help you. However it seems that your question is opinion based- What you expect from "better way"?

What is the better way is quite questionable. So, the following MWE is

pure tikz picture
at least code is shorter in comparison with yours:

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\usepackage{amssymb}
                
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
angle radius = 4mm,
   ma/.style = {fill=#1, semitransparent},
every node/.append style = {font=\small}
                        ]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (5,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,2.5);
\coordinate (D) at (7,2.5);
\draw (A) -- node {$||$} node[pos=0.7,] {$\blacktriangleright\blacktriangleright$} (B) 
          -- node {|} node[pos=0.7] {$\blacktriangleright$} (D) 
          -- node {$||$} node[pos=0.25,] {$\blacktriangleright\blacktriangleright$} (C) 
          -- node {|} node[pos=0.25] {$\blacktriangleright$} (A);   
\pic [ma=green] {angle=D--B--A};
\pic [ma=green] {angle=A--C--D};
\pic [ma=red] {angle=B--A--C};
\pic [ma=red] {angle=C--D--B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



With tkz-euclide. There is no "triangle" branding. We can create it. But much less simple than zarko's code...
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{t}
{%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-0.5\pgfplotmarksize}} 
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.5\pgfplotmarksize}}
  \pgfpathclose
  \pgfusepathqfill
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/0/B}
\tkzDefShiftPointCoord[B](2,2.5){C}
\tkzDefShiftPointCoord[A](2,2.5){D}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,...,D)
%
\tkzFillAngle[fill=green,size=.4](C,B,A)
\tkzFillAngle[fill=green,size=.4](A,D,C)
\tkzFillAngle[fill=orange,size=.6](B,A,D)
\tkzFillAngle[fill=orange,size=.6](D,C,B)
%
\tkzMarkSegments[mark=|,size=5pt](A,D B,C);
\tkzMarkSegments[mark=||,size=5pt](A,B C,D);
%
\tkzMarkSegments[mark=t,pos=0.7,size=5pt](A,B B,C C,D D,A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


